# Standard Deviation and Mean using Chebyshev's Theorem

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, percentages, means

Find the standard deviation and mean when The sale prices of 88.9% of the homes in a certain neighborhood were between \$438,572 and \$189,992.

From Chebyshev's theorem it is known that 88.9% is 3 standard deviations(k) from the mean.

(mean+k*std dev ) = upper bound

(mean-k*std dev ) = lower bound

I was going to use the Upper and Lower Bound equation to find the inverse so I can get the mean but I am missing the standard deviation that goes with the mean. I don't know any other way to try and solve this

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

So let $m,s$ be mean and std dev, you have $k=3$ and your equations yield
$$
m + 3s = 438572\\
m - 3s = 189992
$$
Can you solve 2 equations for 2 unknowns?

**HINT 2**
What happens when you add the equations to each other?